# Проблема в написании тг бота на библиотеке aiogram на языке python

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня возникла проблема в том, что надо вызвать функцию с аргументом message из функции с аргументом callback, я перепробовал множество способов но все они либо были слишком запутанными, либо не рабочими в моей ситуации

Функция из которой нужно вызвать:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='odd_casik')
async def even_number(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await randomizer(callback)
    if random_number % 2 == 0:
        await callback.message.answer(f'Выпало:  {random_number}.  Вы проиграли!!!')
        await casino_state_bet(message, state)
    else:
        await callback.message.answer(f'Выпало:  {random_number}.  Вы выиграли!!!')
        await casino_state_bet(message, state)
```

Функция которую нужно вызвать:

```
async def casino_state_bet(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global bet_pl
    await sqlite.balance_info(message)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['bet'] = message.text
    bet_pl = int(data['bet'])
    if bet_pl > sqlite.balance:
        await message.answer('Недостаточно средств!!!')
        await state.finish()
        await casino_bet_message(message)
    else:
        await message.answer('На что хотите поставить?', reply_markup=btn_casik)
        await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='odd_casik')
async def even_number(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await randomizer(callback)
    if random_number % 2 == 0:
        await callback.message.answer(f'Выпало:  {random_number}.  Вы проиграли!!!')
        await casino_state_bet(callback.message, state)
    else:
        await callback.message.answer(f'Выпало:  {random_number}.  Вы выиграли!!!')
        await casino_state_bet(callback.message, state)
```

Я даже посмеялся чуток, вы сами же в этом же хендлере обращаетесь к месседжу и при этом спрашиваете как это сделать =)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ну я только начал разбираться в данной теме и возникают глупые вопросы, которые решаются очень легко, но догадаться не получается. Еще раз спасибо))